# A question about a single-line calculator in java?

Tags: java

so, I was trying to solve a question about creating a single line calculator on code forces that takes the input in just one line as following "1+2" and outputs the answer 3
my code works fine with single digits
but when it comes to double digits as the following :
"7+54" gives "12" and that indicates that the compiler does not recognize "4" so why is that happening ?

also, I want to note that the accepted format of the calculator on code forces is for example '1+2' not     "1 + 2" that is why I used this line of code`String inputWithSpaces = input.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ");` that separates between the string characters with spaces. I did that because if i wrote "1+2"no spaces
this gave me error

```
import java.util.*;
 
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      
 String input = in.nextLine();
        String inputWithSpaces = input.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 "); // this code gives spaces to string input to be accepted in parseINT
            String sum[] =inputWithSpaces .split(" ");
            /*  i took the whole expression in one single string line then i splitted it and
stored it in an array called sum , then by parseInt i was able to identify the type of each element in the arrays indexes
i couldnot identify the operator as char as i cant convert string into char so , i used char O=operator.charAt(0) to conv the string into
char
 
             */
 
            long num1 = Integer.parseInt(sum[0]);
            String operator = sum[1];
            long num2 = Integer.parseInt(sum[2]);
 
            char O = operator.charAt(0);  
            switch (O) {
                case '+':
                    System.out.println(num1 + num2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    System.out.println(num1 - num2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    System.out.println(num1 * num2);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(num1 / num2);
                    break;
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what `inputWithSpaces` is for `"7+54"`?

Comment: Your "space injection" workflow is making `7+54` into `7 + 5 4`, so it's not working.  I'd suggesting using a `Scanner` instead

Comment: i think it convert it into "7 + 5 4"

Comment: @MadProgrammer could u give me more info about using Scanner in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just split the original input string on the four operators (+-*/), instead of injecting spaces?

Comment: Even if you got the answer you looking for, ill suggest you to use javascript engine for these kind of calcs. 

System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(input));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

> the compiler does not recognize "4"

Not at all, only your code is a fault `sum[2]` takes one char, the `5`, not `54`. If you have given `12+15` it wouldn't have worked at all.

---

#### Solution

The **minimal** change would be the regex `\D` for non-digit. It would put spaces around the operator

```
input.replaceAll("\\D", " $0 ")

"15+50"   >>   ["15", "+", "50"]
```

The **best** would be to directly split the 3 parts

```
String input = "15+50";
String[] sum = input.split("(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)");

long num1 = Integer.parseInt(sum[0]);
String operator = sum[1];
long num2 = Integer.parseInt(sum[2]);

switch (operator.charAt(0)) {
    case '+' -> System.out.println(num1 + num2);
    case '-' -> System.out.println(num1 - num2);
    case '*' -> System.out.println(num1 * num2);
    default -> System.out.println(num1 / num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split before and after non-digits.

Replace:

```
String inputWithSpaces = input.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ");
String sum[] =inputWithSpaces .split(" ");
```

With:

```
String sum[] = input.split("(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)");
```

Regex breakdown:

- `(?=\\D)` means "the next character is a non-digit"
- `|` is the regex logical `OR` operator
- `(?<=\\D)` means "the preceding character is a non-digit"

Answer (score 0):

I think most people forget that `Scanner` is meant for parsing mixed input, not just user input.

For example, you could easily verify and parse your input using something like...

```
String input = "7+54";

Scanner parser = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("");
if (!parser.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Expecting int value");
    return;
}
int lhs = parser.nextInt();

if (!parser.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Expecting operator");
    return;
}
String operator = parser.next();

if (!parser.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Expecting int value");
    return;
}
int rhs = parser.nextInt();

System.out.println(lhs + " " + operator + " " + rhs);
```

Which will output `7 + 54`